# css background url not working in express

Tags: html, css

I can't create a background image for a section tag in express. I've tried several different paths, including:

```
#image{
background: url('/images/beachPierPanorama.jpg') 50% 0 no-repeat fixed; 
}

#image{
background: url('./images/beachPierPanorama.jpg') 50% 0 no-repeat fixed; 
}

#image{
background: url('../images/beachPierPanorama.jpg') 50% 0 no-repeat fixed; 
}
```

This is a picture of my file directory. The css you see above is located in style.css, and I'm trying to reference the image in the images folder:

```
 ![IMG]http://i58.tinypic.com/dcbrkx.png[/IMG]
```

Comment: I'm trying to see which one will actually load the image into the section tag. An image of the directory structure can be found at http://i58.tinypic.com/dcbrkx.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the pic, the `/images` directory is in `/public` so

```
background: url('../public/images/beachPierPanorama.jpg')....
```

should always work.

Comment: still not working. I wonder if it has something to do with my other css/html and not the file path.