# Css background url path not working in node.js app

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, express

I have a problem finding the correct image path, the only similar question I could find on SO was left unresolved and uses the same technologies.

[css background url not working in express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26579422/css-background-url-not-working-in-express)

The whole app is done in node.js, I am using express for the routing.

I have the contact.html file, this will later be an ejs file, but I think this does not matter for now.
I have the CSS inline in the contact.html file, all in a style tag.

Tried all the paths, ../,/,./ etc, I always get this is the console:

GET http://127.0.0.1:3000/checks.png 404 (Not Found)

I find this very odd, when I use an absolute path, it all works, here is a screenshot of all the folders visible and the CSS part.

[image: nodejsscreenshot]

Can anyone tell me why this is? Especially the weird console error message is bugging me>-)

Comment: could you show the full folder structure?

Comment: That's the full file structure there

Comment: You say you've tried 'all the paths' but you haven't actually given examples of what you've tried. On the face of it it would seem that the correct paths would be `/img/checks.png`, `./img/checks.png` and `img/checks.png`.

Comment: @skirtle
Tried all those and more. Does not work.

Comment: @Sergei
Tried many different url paths, will not work, that is the only error message displayed. This is odd, as my get functions with express do not render the ejs files either. I have put up a new screenshot with all the folders open.

Comment: how error are you have in your browser in devtools:network beside request of current image? Or insert http://127.0.0.1:3000/img/checks.png in browsers adressline. Maybe you have error in permissions. – Сергей Петрашко 30 mins ago

Comment: I tried to create  new app , and all right . my css: background-image: url('/images/1.jpg'); ---all is well.  I thing that your problem is perissions  or   express search files in other folders. Can you add  screen your devtools:network with all requests?

Comment: Sergei, thanks, I am using the atom IDE, listening to port 3000 on localhost. Opens up in the Opera browser. How would I change these permissions and where would that error be displayed? Thank you for the effort.

Comment: press ctrl+shift+i in opera and select networks, reload your page and find line with your image. I hope you don't use vpn in opera))))

Comment: Please update your question to include: 1. The full URL of the page contact.html, 2. The image paths you've tried that don't work, 3. The 'absolute path' that does work, 4. The relevant section of your Express code where you're serving up the files contact.html and checks.png.

Comment: @ptts , if your OS is linux,  your server  may not have permissions use your image

Comment: @skirtle
I had stated the paths I have tried in the original question, really tried them all. 

URL is http://127.0.0.1:3000/contact


URls like these work:

background-image: url(https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-ngRcjH2o1Z8/UDjvxZrbpYI/AAAAAAAABMU/QDFNiStAbZ4/s1600/fractal25.jpg);

<img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81Clj2zVQSL._RI_SX200_.jpg" alt="Image">
and the code:

app.get("/contact", function(req,res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/contact.html');
});

Comment: @ptts. You need to update the question to include that information, it does not belong in a comment. You did not state the paths that you tried in the original question, writing 'Tried all the paths, ../,/,./' tells us very little. You still have not posted the server code that you're using to serve up `checks.png`, usually something involving `express.static`. It would seem from your last comment that when you said 'absolute paths' in the question you were not referring to the absolute path to `checks.png`, which is an important distinction to make: please clarify in the question.

Comment: /img/checks.png this worked for me